# In nest js foreign key constraint are not working properly

Tags: nestjs

I am new this framework. I tried to add one to one relationship and post the data using postman. Data also successfully inserted. SO, I will check the database foreign key field are showing null values. I tried many ways but I couldn't get the answer. How to fix it.

**user.entity.ts**

```
import { CustomerEntity } from "src/customers/customer.entity";
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToOne, JoinColumn} from "typeorm";


@Entity()
export class UserEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column({ type: "integer" })
    userId: number;
        
    @OneToOne(type => CustomerEntity, car => car.user)
    @JoinColumn()
    car: CustomerEntity

}
```

**customer.entity.ts**

```
import { UserEntity } from "src/users/user.entity";
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToOne, PrimaryColumn} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class CustomerEntity {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: number

    @Column({ type: "integer" })
    sample: number;

    @OneToOne(type => UserEntity, user => user.car)
    user: UserEntity | null

}
```

[image]

How to implement one to one relationship in Nest JS I need Working Example code

Answer (score 0):

note that this is not up to nest but to TypeORM. One to one is pretty much what you've done. `CustomerEntity` didn't have primary key, is it right? In that case, read [this about `JoinColumn`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/7eb032705912cbf4ee340ed9e49970d0f6e23714/docs/relations.md#joincolumn-options)